# Is there a function to find the amount of space a text inside a button will take up with any font size, style etc., in Java?

Tags: java, swing, text, fonts, jbutton

As the title says, I'm wondering if there is a function to give me an x and y value for how much space the text will take so I can size my button accordingly. If not, could you please give me a code snippet that you may have to do the same job.

Comment: Beware: _so I can size my button accordingly_ implies that you try to create a UI without using a layout manager. Please don't do that - a layout manager will resize the button (and all the components around it) for you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [FontMetrics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html) class, for example:

```
public static int getTextWidth(Font font, String text) {
    FontMetrics metrics = new FontMetrics(font) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 345265L;
    };
    Rectangle2D bounds = metrics.getStringBounds(text, null);
    return (int) bounds.getWidth();
}

public static int getTextHeight(Font font, String text) {
    FontMetrics metrics = new FontMetrics(font) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 345266L;
    };
    Rectangle2D bounds = metrics.getStringBounds(text, null);
    return (int) bounds.getHeight();
}
```

To use these methods (perhaps in your use case):

```
int width = getTextWidth(jButton1.getFont(), "Hello There World");
int height = getTextHeight(jButton1.getFont(), "Hello There World");
```

Or...use the example shown in the provided link above.